# Why would I want "less info"?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

On every user's profile page there is a toggling button that reduces displayed information about a user, right beside their name, called "less info".

Why would I not want to get the full information about a user when I'm specifically viewing their user profile page? What is the reason this feature exists? Is it a mobile browser thing? Or a small screen thing? Can they not scroll the page?

Comment: Note that the profile page is about to get a makeover: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/the-profile-page-is-getting-a-makeover

Answer (score 6):

The only things that toggle hides are the age field, the number of profile views and the bio. And it reduces the avatar size.

With my usual screen resolution, in *less info* mode, I get to see the *Accounts* and *Votes Cast* "widget" thingies without scrolling.

When I go and check out a profile, I'm generally not interested in the items in the first group, but do like to see those in the second. So for me, the *less info* toggle is misnamed – it in fact lets me see more of information I'm usually interested in at a glance.

Other people just like the collapsed view better. I suspect quite a few people never noticed that link.

Why *you* would prefer one view or the other is a question only you can answer I'm afraid.

Comment: +1 -- note that the collapsed status persists between page loads, so it is actually toggling a preference rather than a page-level toggle to fold up a "read more" section on the current page. I have the "less info" mode turned on as a default.